# Image not appearing in Winforms User Control Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, image, vsto

I am using WPF to code the user interface in a Document level VSTO customisation but I have been unable to get an image in a WPF control to display in the Windows Forms User Control ElementHost designer. I have checked the other posts on this issue on StackOverflow in detail and believe that I have covered all the suggestions but to no avail. Clearly I am missing something and I should be very grateful for some advice. Below is a detailed description of what I have done.

For illustration the user interface for this example is just the display of a single logo image.

I am following the instructions for [Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772076.aspx).

I create a new Office project (TestWPFImage) for a document level customisation from the Word 2013 and Word 2016 Template provided in Visual Studio 2017 v15.6.7

I add a User Control(WPF) (UserControlWPF.xaml) to the project.

I add an Image (RPLogo.png) to the project.

I set the properties of RPLogo.png as follows

[image: RPLogoProperties settings in Project].

I have also tried changing the build action from Content to Resource but it made no difference.

I add the following Xaml code to UserControlWPF.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Image Margin="10" Source="pack://application:,,,/RPLogo.png" />
</Grid
```

The image appears in the WPF control designer as follows

[image: UserControlXamlDesigner]

I build the project creating the WPF control in the toolbox as follows

[image: UserControlWPFInToolbox]

I add a WinForms user control (UserControlWinForms) to the project. My project now looks like this in solution explorer.

[image: TestWPFImageInSolutionExplorer]

I open the UserControlWinForms Windows Forms User Control designer and from the TestImageWPF User Controls tab of the Toolbox, I drag the WPF user control to the designer but the image does not appear.

[image]

Comment: huh?What?wpf or winforms.....?My head is spinning.......Where did you get `Windows Forms Host` in `WinForms` ?!

Comment: I am following the instructions for Using WPF Controls in Office Solutions at the link given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you cannot see the `Image` you added in the `User-control` then u need to use pack URI for that :

```
  <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/image.png"/>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry edit update overran the 5 minutes! ....I am using the pack URI as in the code quoted <Image Margin="10" Source="pack://application:,,,/RPLogo.png" /> My understanding from MSDNs dissertation on Pack URIs in WPF at thelink given is that this is the correct structure when compiling into a local assembly. The version you have given I understood to be appropriate for a referenced assembly. Notwithstanding I have tried both forms and neither work.

Comment: @January59 , the pack URI will work if your image's `Build action` is set to `Resource`

Comment: Hi zack - many thanks, the combination of using what I understood to be the referenced assembly form rather than the local assembly form (have I misunderstood all that) and changing the Build Action from Content to Resource has solved the problem and finally it appears!

Comment: For me, the solution was to set the Build Action to Resource, but then have the URI look like  <Image Source="/YourAssemblyName;component/image.png"/>. Not sure why.

Comment: @gusmallysupportsMonica That's what i pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @AousafRashid what I was trying to highlight was that the URI was different (the "pack://application:,,," part is not there)